# How to get child JsonNode with a Jayway JsonPath

Tags: jackson, jsonpath

Here're my use case:

*Given a JsonNode (already parsed by Jackson), I'd like to provide a list of Jayway JsonPath to select sub JsonNodes that I'm interested.*

i.e:

```java
List<JsonNode> getSubNodes(JsonNode root, List<String> jsonPaths)
```

(Given the fact that my own library/Utils are built on Jackson API, so I want everything in memory is in Jackson model)

Is it doable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jayway JsonPath is shipped with five different `JsonProviders`.  Refer this link : https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jsonprovider-spi

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the present moment it is not possible to directly use pre-parsed JSON in form of Jackson JsonNode with Jayway JsonPath.

Either, a priori, parse it with the JSON providers mentioned in the comment of the original post or write the JSON node to String and re-parse with JsonPath.

For Example:

```
                Object o=JsonPath.read(new ObjectMapper()
                                        .writeValueAsString(n), 
                                        "$.classRelationships[*].targetClassName");
```

where 'n' is the JsonNode

***The above is very very inefficient***. I could not find any other way by going through the documentation.

If anyone has a better approach, I also would like to know. as I have the same requirement.